# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added Lokio/AsyncTimeout

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mapbox, xbuild

I am trying to get the MapBox component working in my Xamarin app.

At first I was just referencing a mapbox.dll in my references in my Android project. Using that method, the app would crash when trying to inflate a layout containing mapbox.

I dereferenced the mapbox.dll and added the mapbox component to my Android project in hopes that it will fix my problem. However, at compile time I am now getting this error:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets: Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added :  Lokio/AsyncTimeout; (IM.Droid)
```

I have dereferenced the previous mapbox.dll, deleted it, cleaned, deleted all the obj and bin directories... still getting the same error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the sources of the MapBox component/NuGet/dll? Also if you have a sample project that you can upload to dropbox and link here, I can check this out for you soon.

Comment: Never use Xamarin. That is the most buggiest app I've ever seen. Really dont's use it.

Answer (score 2):

Remove ModernHttpClient reference from droid project.

Comment: We need modern http client to avoid the certificate pinning problems. Do you have any other solution?